# nonsubsampled Contourlet decomposition

Tags: matlab, mex

I have an image (medical image) 1024*1024 I'm trying to decompose it using the NSCT toolbox but every time I run the code I got this error:

[image]

```
This error was detected while a MEX-file was running. If the MEX-file
is not an official MathWorks function, please examine its source code
for errors. Please consult the External Interfaces Guide for information
on debugging MEX-files.
```

the only mex files I'm using are the ones in the Toolbox

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10049-nonsubsampled-contourlet-toolbox

```
nlevels = [0, 1, 3] ;        % Decomposition level
pfilter = 'maxflat' ;              % Pyramidal filter
dfilter = 'dmaxflat7' ;              % Directional filter

% Nonsubsampled Contourlet decomposition
coeffs = nsctdec( double(im), nlevels, dfilter, pfilter );
```

Comment: Please post your code, or a minimal, complete, verifiable example based on your code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: the code is in the toolbox decdemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this error because the mex files were not the right ones, my system is windows7 64 bit the mex files are .mexmac